# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper doesn't remove item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I'm trying to implement swipe to archive note in RecyclerView.
 It was working fine but after I added these codes to refresh the RecyclerView from `onResume()`, Swiping although does archive the Note, but the item doesn't get removed and stays at a state you can see in image below:

[image]

This is what I do in `onResume()` :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        notes = noteDAO.getAllNotes();
        noteAdapter = new NoteAdapter(notes,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
    }
```

ItemTouchHelper `onSwiped()`:

```
@Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        noteAdapter.deleteItem(position,rv);
    }
```

`deleteItem` method in Adapter:

```
    public void deleteItem(int position, RecyclerView rv) {
            noteDAO = DBInjector.provideNoteDao(context);
            recentlyDeletedNote = notes.get(position);
            recentlyDeletedNotePosition = position;
            recentlyDeletedNote.setArchive(true);
            notes.remove(position);
            noteDAO.archiveNote(recentlyDeletedNote);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

Comment: you want to swipe to remove.

Comment: Yes @InfusionAnalysts

Comment: refer this demo https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a lot of solutions, the only reason why it is not updating the view is that on updating recycler views, views are getting updated especially when **ItemTouchHelper** is used. As I didn't have much choice I used

> **recreate()**

function for refreshing the whole activity and the error went off.

PS: This is not the ideal solution, it is just workaround fix.